# Multiple checkbox are checked when selecting single checkbox in iTextShap

Tags: c#, checkbox, itext

I want to create a editable pdf which has multiple check box below is the code if i check one check box all are getting checked.

```
PdfPCell tbCellck3 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("", helvetica12));
tbCellck3.Colspan = 1;
RadioCheckField checkBox3 = new RadioCheckField(writer, new iTextSharp.text.Rectangle(5, 5), "noDelete", "Yes");
checkBox3.CheckType = RadioCheckField.TYPE_CHECK;
PdfFormField field3 = checkBox3.CheckField;
writer.AddAnnotation(field3);
iTextSharp.text.pdf.events.FieldPositioningEvents eventscheckBox3 = new   iTextSharp.text.pdf.events.FieldPositioningEvents(writer, field3);
tbCellck3.CellEvent = eventscheckBox3;
subAEtable.AddCell(tbCellck3);
PdfPCell tbCellP6 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Substitution approved as noted - Make submittals in accordance with Specification Section 01 25 00 Substitution Procedures.", helvetica12));
tbCellP6.Colspan = 3;
tbCellP6.Border = PdfCell.NO_BORDER;
 subAEtable.AddCell(tbCellP6);

PdfPCell tbCellck4 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("", helvetica12));
 tbCellck4.Colspan = 1;
RadioCheckField checkBox4 = new RadioCheckField(writer, new iTextSharp.text.Rectangle(5, 5), "noDelete", "Yes");
checkBox4.CheckType = RadioCheckField.TYPE_CHECK;
PdfFormField field4 = checkBox4.CheckField;
writer.AddAnnotation(field4);
iTextSharp.text.pdf.events.FieldPositioningEvents eventscheckBox4 = new     iTextSharp.text.pdf.events.FieldPositioningEvents(writer, field4);
tbCellck4.CellEvent = eventscheckBox4;
subAEtable.AddCell(tbCellck4);
PdfPCell tbCellP7 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Substitution rejected - use specified materials.", helvetica12));
tbCellP7.Colspan = 3;
tbCellP7.Border = PdfCell.NO_BORDER;
subAEtable.AddCell(tbCellP7);
```

Answer (score 2):

You (probably by accident) used the autofill functionality.
The reason is the same name `noDelete` which is the 3rd parameter of the RadioCheckField constructor.

```
RadioCheckField checkBox3 = new RadioCheckField(writer, new iTextSharp.text.Rectangle(5, 5), "noDelete", "Yes");
checkBox3.CheckType = RadioCheckField.TYPE_CHECK;
PdfFormField field3 = checkBox3.CheckField;
writer.AddAnnotation(field3);

RadioCheckField checkBox4 = new RadioCheckField(writer, new iTextSharp.text.Rectangle(5, 5), "noDelete", "Yes");
checkBox4.CheckType = RadioCheckField.TYPE_CHECK;
PdfFormField field4 = checkBox4.CheckField;
PdfFormField field4 = checkBox4.CheckField;
writer.AddAnnotation(field4);
```

If you change it to unique names (like `noDelete1`and `noDelete2`you'll get your desired behavior:

```
RadioCheckField checkBox3 = new RadioCheckField(writer, new iTextSharp.text.Rectangle(5, 5), "noDelete1", "Yes");
checkBox3.CheckType = RadioCheckField.TYPE_CHECK;
PdfFormField field3 = checkBox3.CheckField;
writer.AddAnnotation(field3);

RadioCheckField checkBox4 = new RadioCheckField(writer, new iTextSharp.text.Rectangle(5, 5), "noDelete2", "Yes");
checkBox4.CheckType = RadioCheckField.TYPE_CHECK;
PdfFormField field4 = checkBox4.CheckField;
PdfFormField field4 = checkBox4.CheckField;
writer.AddAnnotation(field4);
```

One additional hint:
Try to find meaningful names which describe the field. E.g. 'AgreementCheck', "SurveyOptionA" and so on. This helps when later the form data is extracted and evaluated.